# Android NDK native call input and output stream

Tags: android, android-ndk, stdio

hi i've achieved it to compile a c programm with NDK for my android project.

Now i'm able to call it's main function.

Now i need the read/write to the input/output stream of the native process.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you do it that way you'll need to make some pipes or even a pty (if allowed).  You will probably also want to call its main() from a thread.

Comment: Did you build a shared library or an executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not really the answer, but at least with this i can fetch what the programm is outputting

in c  i call this before running the other functions

```
freopen("/storage/emulated/0/stdoutfile","w",stdout);
freopen("/storage/emulated/0/stderrfile","w",stderr);
```